# How to submit form with data converted into Big5

Tags: javascript, html, forms, character-encoding, big5

So I have a page, and try to submit a form along with user-entered data.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Cck8Q/

However, the browser sends out the data in UTF-8, while the server requires it to be in Big5.  Basically this means,

```
encodeURIComponent("電")    //"%E9%9B%BB"
```

this is not using the correct character set, and the correct string should be

```
%B9q
```

Is there anyway to "make" the browser to send the data using Big5? JavaScript conversion indeed is possible, but it would end up like [this](http://www.code-club.idv.tw/index.php?action=index&run=article_read&ClassID=37&ArticleID=1531).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only looking for encoding in HTML form submission, not JS encoding conversion, you can take advantage of the `accept` attribute (HTML4) and/or `accept-charset` attribute (HTML5) of `<form>`:

```
<form action="..." method="get" accept="BIG5" accept-charset="BIG5">
```

[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cck8Q/5/) (Checked on a Chrome on XP Simplified Chinese version).

[MDN document about `<form>` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes)